# AWS Managed Blockchain - Hyperledger fabric Error: could not assemble transaction notarget No matching version found for fabric-shim@^1.4.2

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm creating a hyperledger contract similar to the [commercial paper example](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.htm) in typescript and publishing it in a AWS Managed Blockchain Service using this command:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true" \
-e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem" \
-e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=$MSP" \
-e  "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$MSP_PATH" \
-e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=$PEER" \
cli peer chaincode instantiate -o $ORDERER \
-C ourchannel --lang node -n papercontract -v v0 \
-c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' \
--cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls \
-P "AND ('$ORG1','$ORG2')"
```

I already installed the contract using this command in both organizations:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true" \
-e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem" \
-e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=$MSP" \
-e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$MSP_PATH" \
-e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=$PEER" \
cli peer chaincode install --lang node -n papercontract -v v0 \
-p chaincode
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
$ checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
$ checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
$ Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg failed to execute transaction f0803ce6160119859cedd426e5d4d35dfba3ee6fa0653078ef917546b1854ea7: error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for fabric-shim@^1.4.2
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'transference-contract'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-15T18_22_42_519Z-debug.log
"
```

I have run `npm install` and `npm run build` in my client and everything works fine. The problem seems to be that the library isn't downloaded in the peer inside the blockchain, but as it is managed I can't really see inside of it to see what's happening.

Can you give me some ideas to whats happening? what can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The peer nodes do not support the fabric-shim 1.4 version

According to the AWS docs:

> Managed Blockchain peer nodes use version 1.2 of the fabric-shim library to provide the low-level chaincode interface between applications, peers, and the Hyperledger Fabric system for chaincode applications using Node.js. All chaincode has a dependency on this library. Dependencies on other versions or other library packages are not supported because peer nodes currently do not have access to the NPM repository.

Snippet is from this page from aws: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-hyperledger-write-and-run-chaincode.html